# Función Async con Mongoose y NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, express, mongoose

Estoy intentando hacer una función asíncrona con Node.JS, Express y Mongoose para que guarde el valor y luego retorne el resultado. Pero se ejecuta antes el `console.log` que hay fuera del `await` en vez del que hay dentro.

Dejo la función:

```
async function createAddress() {
  const address = new Address();

  address.location = "";

  await address.save((err, addressStored) => {
     console.log("Dentro");
  });
  console.log("Fuera");
}
```

Comment: Te puede ser de utilidad este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832010/mongoose-await-save)

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás mezclando funciones [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona) con llamadas a funciones [`callback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) dentro del método [`save()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) de Mongoose.

Según la documentación de Mongoose: (traducción propia)

> «Promise,undefined» Devuelve `undefined` si es usado con una función `callback`, sino devuelve una [`Promesa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise).

Dicho esto, lo que debes hacer es llamar al método sin pasar la función `callback`.

Además, dado que el método `save()` devuelve una Promesa, debemos usar un bloque [`try catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/try...catch) para capturar el caso en que la Promesa sea rechazada.

Tu código podría quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
async function createAddress() {
  const address = new Address();
  address.location = '';
  // usamos await dentro de un bloque try catch
  try {
    await address.save();
    console.log('Satisfactorio');
    // acciones en caso que addres.save() sea satisfactorio
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    // acciones en caso de error
  }
  console.log('Fuera'); // <= fuera del bloque try catch
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.